# Invalid matching of DomainNameMapping?

Tags: netty

I have the following DomainNameMapping which contains the following two mappings.

> "*.app.example.com"   =>       A
>
> "*.example.com"       =>       B

When I try to map a host of "app.example.com" I receive output A. I would expect that the DomainNameMapping would instead match against "*.example.com" and output B would be returned.

Looking at the Netty source code this seems to be satisfying the first condition of the matches(String, String) method.

```
static boolean matches(String template, String hostName) {
        if (template.startsWith("*.")) {
            return template.regionMatches(2, hostName, 0, hostName.length())
                || commonSuffixOfLength(hostName, template, template.length() - 1);
        }
        return template.equals(hostName);
}
```

Namely, `template.regionMatches(2, hostName, 0, hostName.length())` is true in this case. Why is this case allowed to match? It seems to me that the template should only match hostNames that are have some subdomain prefixed on the root domain defined by the wildcard found in the DomainNameMapping.